# How to sort duplicated values in igraph plot in R?

Tags: r, igraph

There is an `igraph` plot. I want to sort manually the position of lines.
[image]

For example, in the above plot, the **Tamiang** line must take place at the second line at the top, and **Sigulai -> ERROR -> NA** line takes place at bottom of the plot.
This is the data:

```
dput(sample)
structure(list(NMSUKU = c("Aceh/ Achin/ Akhir/ Asji/ A-Tse/ Ureung Aceh", 
"Alas", "Aneuk Jamee", "Gayo", "Gayo Lut", "Gayo Luwes", "Gayo Serbe Jadi", 
"Kluet", "Sigulai", "Simeulue", "Simeulue", "Simeulue", "Singkil", 
"Singkil", "Tamiang"), TopLang = c("Aceh/ Acheh/ Achi ", "Alas ", 
"Aceh Jamee ", "Gajo/ Gayo ", "Gajo/ Gayo ", "Gajo/ Gayo ", "Gajo/ Gayo ", 
"Aceh Kluet ", "ERROR  TopCol out of range ", "Long Bano/ Simalur/ Simeuloe/ Simeulue/ Simulul ", 
"Aceh Simeleu Barat ", "Aceh Simeleu Tengah ", "Aceh Hulu Singkil ", 
"Aceh Hulu Singkil ", "Tamiang "), Ethnicity = c("1_Aceh/ Achin/ Akhir/ Asji/ A-Tse/ Ureung Aceh  ", 
"2_Alas  ", "3_Aneuk Jamee  ", "4_Gayo  ", "6_Gayo Luwes  ", 
"5_Gayo Lut  ", "7_Gayo Serbe Jadi  ", "8_Kluet  ", "NA  ", "10_Simeulue  ", 
"10_Simeulue  ", "10_Simeulue  ", "11_Singkil  ", "17_Batak Pakpak Dairi  ", 
"12_Tamiang  ")), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is the code:

```
Library(igraph)
m <- as.matrix(replace(sample, sample == "", "NA"))
g <- simplify(graph_from_edgelist(rbind(m[, 1:2], m[, 2:3]), directed = TRUE))
l <- layout_with_sugiyama(g)
plot(g,
  layout = -l$layout[, 2:1],
  edge.arrow.size = 0.1,
  vertex.size = 2.5,
  vertex.color = "grey",
  vertex.label.dist = 1,
  edge.arrow.width = 1.5,
  edge.width = seq(0.5, 0.08),
  edge.lty = "solid",
  edge.color = "gray",
  vertex.label.cex = 0.7,
  is.rm = TRUE,
  vertex.label.color = "black"
)
```

Want I want to get like this one:
[image]
I think this one create manually. Anyway the diagram final should be the same as this one and can order the position of the item too.

Thank you!

Comment: *"the Tamiang line must take place at the second line at the top, and Sigulai -> ERROR -> NA line takes place at bottom of the plot"* What are the general rules for sorting the nodes?

Comment: @Maurits that is the problem which I don't know. Because posted it.

Comment: How can we help if you don't tell us how to sort the nodes? What are the rules? What determines which terms are at the top and which are at the bottom? What determines the order? We can only help with the implementation. You need to explain the logic!

Comment: @Kian can you provide the code (/ packages) that you used to generate the image?

Comment: @slamballais and Maurits I have added the codes that ran for making plot.

Answer (score 0):

In your layout generator, there is an argument `layers` that takes a list of sub-networks. If you manually create this list in the order you want, the Sugiyama will follow this order and plot the networks as specified.

```
layers = list(c("Tamiang","Tamiang","12_Tamiang"),
              c("Alas","Alas","2_Alas"),
              ....))
```

And then you call the layout with this layers list:

```
l <- layout_with_sugiyama(g, layers=apply(sapply(layers,function(x) V(g)$name %in% x), 1, which))
```

There is only one small problem: Your node identifiers are not unique. You'll have to make them unique to make the `sapply()` function work properly in this example.

Also check the manual for additional information on this layout:
https://igraph.org/r/doc/layout_with_sugiyama.html

Comment: Yes, the node identifiers are not unique. I stuck here, do not how to do.

Comment: Just make them unique. You got your data from somewhere, right? In the process of grabbing the data and putting it into your structured list, just change the names of the elements to unique identifiers (e.g. paste "lang_" as a prefix to all languages).

Comment: I have added the number and prefix. got the same problem. As you see **Gajo/ Gayo** to add the number or prefix. still, it is duplicate.

Comment: Do you know any to solve the problem? Anyway, I really appreciate your answering.

Comment: The solution to this problem will lie in data preprocessing. SInce I do not know your original data, it's hard to make clear suggestions.

Comment: Thank you Martin. Is there any other way to draw the diagram. I have added a sample to my question you can see it.